# Batch rename pc by prepending the current pc name

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, registry, windows-xp

Background:

I am migrating several thousand computers from xp to 7 as a sub-contractor. The computers are on a domain. We have admin rights to add, modify and delete computers from the domain. When we first approach a xp machine, we have to add "delete" in front of the name and rename it (example: old name "pc12345" new name "deletepc12345"). I am working on a batch file that will help with this process, but I am running into some trouble.

Script:

```
@echo off

SET /P PCNAME=delete%computername%
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ActiveComputerName\ /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ /v Hostname /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ /v "NV Hostname" /t REG_SZ /d %PCNAME% /f
@echo off
echo Please Restart your computer Manually. The Program will exit now.
echo.
echo.
pause
```

Issue:
After running the batch file. The computer name is changed to "/f" instead of the "deletepc12345"

Comment: Change your `@echo off` to `@echo on` and look at what it's running.  Probably `PCNAME` is being set to an empty string and you're ending up with "/d /f".  I have a feeling the `set /p` doesn't work the way you think it works.  Get rid of `/p` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `/p` from `set /p PCNAME=...`.  What that's doing is prompting the user for input and merely printing "delete%computername%" to the screen.  What you want is simply

```
set "PCNAME=delete%computername%"
```

As it is now, probably PCNAME ends up being an empty string and `/d %PCNAME% /f` is being evaluated as "/d /f".

If you change `@echo off` to `@echo on`, your script will print each line as it runs and you can see exactly what's being evaluated.